# Редактирование сообщения после нажатия inline кнопки. Бот для telegram на Python, aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Пытаюсь написать бота с inline-режимом на python с помощью библиотеки aiogram.
Хочу, чтобы он работал следующим образом

1. Вызов бота через @ в чат
2. В ответ бот присылает сообщение с кнопкой
3. После нажатия кнопки клавиатура пропадает, а текст сообщения изменяется

Проблема с третьим пунктом - редактированием предыдущего сообщения.
Была мысль использовать bot.edit_message_text(), но ему нужен chat_id, но ни callback ни inline query вроде бы не могут получить айди чата?

````
#функция создания клавиатуры
def kbcreator():
    test_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, one_time_keyboard=True)
    test_button1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Тест 1", callback_data='test_cb')
    test_kb.add(test_button1)
    return test_kb

#код inline handler`а
@dp.inline_handler()
async def inline_echo(inline_query: InlineQuery):
    if inline_query.query.startswith('t'):
        text = 'its working'
        test_kb1 = kbcreator()
        item = InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id='2',
            title='work',
            reply_markup=test_kb1,
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(text),
        )
        await bot.answer_inline_query(inline_query.id, results=[item], cache_time=1)

#код callback handler`a
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='test_cb')
async def test_callback(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    a = ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    bot.edit_message_text(text='test change', chat_id='???', reply_markup=a)
    await callback.answer('button is working')```
````

Comment: Не могли бы вы предоставить попытки решения? Это можно сделать через [edit]

Comment: Добавил код, который, как мне кажется, должен работать, если достать chat id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смари в зависимости от того что это у тебя за хендлер

```
@dp.message_handler(text="but1")
async def rand_name(msg: types.Message):
    await msg.edit_text("text")

@dp.callback_query_handler(text="but1")
async def rand_name(call: types.Callback_Query):
    await call.message.edit_text("text")

# для инлайн режимной клавиатуры
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="but1")
async def rand_name(call: types.Callback_Query
    await bot.edit_message_text(text="text", inline_message_id=call.inline_message_id)
```

Comment: При использовании второго варианта ошибка "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit_text'"

Comment: @Vladi Покажи код. И вы случаем не удаляете сообщение?

Comment: @Vladi попробуй в колбек хендлере принтануть call.message до каких либо движений

Comment: Код добавил в тело вопроса, по сути, это почти всё, кроме импортов. 
`@dp.callback_query_handler(text='test_cb')
async def test_callback(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    print('Принтую callback.message')
    print(callback.message)
    await callback.message.edit_text("text")` 
явно не удаляю, вся работа бота по сути представлена в этих двух хэндлерах. 
По итогу принтуется "None"

Comment: @Vladi а принтани колбек, что в нем? И заодно кинь свою клавиатуру, то как ты ее создаешь

Comment: Вот принт колбека  {"id": "832921838268232566", "from": {"id": айди моего телеграмма, "is_bot": false, "first_name": "Name", "username": "MyUsername", "language_code": "ru"}, "inline_message_id": "AgAAAHrFAgD_IY8L4wX9O1jMgxM", "chat_instance": "-8941390685584147941", "data": "test_cb"}. Код клавиатуры добавил в тело вопроса.

Comment: @Vladi а попробуй убрать one_time_keyboard=Truе. Вполне возможно что именно из-за него эта проблема. Ты в любом случае в хендлере сможешь убрать ее, если понадобится, просто в edit_text сделай reply_markup=None или же вообще не заполняй reply_markup.

Comment: убрал, к сожалению всё так же, поля message в коллбэк не появилось.

Comment: Давай по новой. Попробуй вот так await bot.editMessageText(text="text", inline_message_id=callback.inline_message_id)

Comment: Упс имел ввиду bot.edit_message_text(...

Comment: Заработало, спасибо большое!